# Getting a "Cannot set property of null" Error on an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. I iteratively create a div element for all the items found in my response.data[]. I also create a checkbox and a text box for each item, giving them an id equal to the "j". I set an addEventListener on each of the checkboxes. Upon clicking a checkbox, it should enable the corresponding text box. However, I am obtaining the following error instead: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null at HTMLInputElement.eval". What am I missing?

ANSWER: This code works. I had an error, which was fixed. I did not delete the post, for there was an answer.

```
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          var jsres = response.data[j]
          div = document.createElement('div')
          div.className = 'sellDiv'
          div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
          div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('On Sale: '))
          let checkbox = document.createElement('input')
          checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
          checkbox.setAttribute('id', j)
          if (jsres.ForSale === true) {
            checkbox.checked = true
          } else {
            checkbox.checked = false
          }
          checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
              document.getElementById('Price' + this.id).disabled = false
            } else {
              document.getElementById('Price' + this.id).disabled = true
            }
          })
          div.appendChild(checkbox)
          div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
          div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Sale Price: '))
          let text = document.createElement('input')
          text.setAttribute('id', 'Price' + j)
          if (jsres.ForSale === true) {
            text.disabled = false
          } else {
            text.disabled = true
          }
          text.setAttribute('value', jsres.Price)
          div.appendChild(text)
          div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
          divArea.appendChild(div)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the line, whether you use ' ' in html id attribute or not
if you done means make space here

```
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          document.getElementById('Price ' + this.id).disabled = false
        } else {
          document.getElementById('Price ' + this.id).disabled = true
        }
      })
```

Comment: Thank you @Balaji Sivasakthi I have added an hyphen but this did not help. I do not understand how this would change anything.

Comment: i don't know what id attribute you mentioned in html. Some people follow this kind of naming.

Comment: Actually, I have just found the issue. Thank you again @Balaji Sivasakthi

Comment: make space over there

Answer (score 0):

`j` value is 0 to size (number)
and here you add `Price` for the id Selector

```
document.getElementById('Price' + this.id).disabled = false
```